# How do I get the external storage's path?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a file to my phone.

I used `Environment.getDataDirectory()` to know the internal storage's path and `Environment.getExternamStorageDirectory()` to know the external storage's path.

But when I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` as path, the file is created in **internal storage**. And when I use `Environment.GetDataStorage()` as the path, the file is not created. (I am not sure, but I can't find it in the explorer app, at least.)

I think my phone's internal storage is perceived as external storage.(In my case, it has 32 GB amount of storage)

I want to know removable storage(e.g. `micro SD card`) path. What should I do?

Comment: I think you need to refer to : 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13648873/6127411  && 
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/6127411

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the official documentation for [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

> Don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
> can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
> can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
> all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
> an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
> device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
> mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

So, it can be different from built-in storage in a device.

For your case, you could use [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

> This is where the user will typically place and manage their own
> files
>
> The path here should be one of DIRECTORY_MUSIC, DIRECTORY_PODCASTS,
> DIRECTORY_RINGTONES, DIRECTORY_ALARMS, DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS,
> DIRECTORY_PICTURES, DIRECTORY_MOVIES, DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, or
> DIRECTORY_DCIM. May not be null.

Or if you want your data to be deleted whenever the user uninstalls your app, you could use [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

As these files are internal to the applications, and not typically visible to the user as media.

Also there are some differences between [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) and [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

1. External files are not always available: they will disappear if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it. See the APIs on environment for information in the storage state.
2. There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files.

Comment: I used `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` but download path just changes from `/storage/emulated/0` to `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.(still built-in storage) Do you know why?

Comment: I think you should see the answer by commonsware http://stackoverflow.com/a/23030038/2319390 , be sure to look at his Blog post series

Comment: Could you please elaborate this sentence "External files are not always available: they will disappear if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it"? To my understanding files will be hidden when user will mount his device to PC. But which mount mode Google is talking about? When I connect my device to PC, I am able to see all the files on PC which stored at above path. Please explain the above sentence. Thank in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
static String storagestate = Environment.getExternalStorageState();



    private static FileOutputStream outStream;
    private static File imageFilepath;

    public static String saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File folder = null;

        // Check for SD card
        if (storagestate.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "*YourStorageNameInDevice");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
            outStream = null;

            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                    .format(new Date());

            // Getting filepath
            imageFilepath = new File(folder.getPath() + File.separator
                    + timestamp + ".PNG");
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFilepath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return imageFilepath.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there something missing (in the sample code)?