# The directory construction of Android

Tags: android

I list a directory construction of Android.

1. I find the directory are same when list directory with these path /sdcard, /storage/sdcard0, /storage/emulated/legacy/and storage/emulated/0/, why?
2. The function `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` can return /storage/emulated/0, I hope to return /storage/extSdCard/, which funation should I use?
3. In my android mobile phone, the /storage/extSdCard/ point to a removable SD card, does the SD card belong to External Storage ? You know storage/emulated/0/ point to my phone memory Card! What are different between extSdCard and External Storage ?

**Root**
[image]

**sdcard**
[image]

**storage**
[image]

**storage/sdcard0/**
[image]

**storage/emulated/0/**
[image]

**storage/extSdCard/**
[image]

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28427267/4625829) before?

Comment: Thanks! I have read that Post.